# WCF with security mode="Message" offline

Tags: wcf

I've got a service that can communicate with a GUI via WCF.
In the app.config I currently have this security configuration:

```
<security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
        algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

If the GUI is installed in the same PC of the service, I would like to establish a communication without being connected to the network. I can do it only if I modify the app.config setting:

```
<security mode="None" />
```

Is there any "universal" solution that keeps the security but works "offline"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have your security set to "message", I suspect you actually have no security (encryption) at all. "Message" security means you're using certificates, on both the host and client, to encrypt the XML located inside your transmission. So if you're not passing XML, or if you're not using common SSL certs stored on both the host and client (even if it's the same machine), you're not really encrypting anything. (It's easy to verify this using a packet sniffer or program like Fiddler)

The only other option for security (encryption) is transport, which is SSL used the old-fashion way. But why would you need to encrypt information traveling between points "A" and "B" on the same machine? I wouldn't even worry about it over an internal network, as long as your network is secure.

Encryption is needed when you traverse publc networks like the WWW, where bad people, or the NSA, is snooping for useful information.

Comment: Strange usage of the word "or"

Comment: But yeah...agreed. For localhost HTTP, "traffic" would be only going through memory, in the case of windows, you would likely be using shared memory. The only way to "intercept" the "traffic" would be to access that shared memory. If you have unrestricted access to the memory, then you would have access to the encryption keys. *Ergo your crytotext is in the same place as your keys.*